# How to add Bootstrap css styles and classes to meteor autoform

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-autoform

How to add bootstrap css an classes to input fields which created using meteor autoform?

```
{{> quickForm collection="Appointments" id="insertAppointmentsForm" class="new-Appointments-form" type="insert"}}
```

[image: I need to make my page like this image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to use jQuery, you can easily throw in some Bootstrap classes that suite your needs.

```
$('#insertAppointmentsForm').addClass('col-md-6');
```

Of course you could need to add some timeout if the autoform loads after the initial jQuery, since the element has to be there in order for jQuery to pick up the ID and throw in your custom classes.

**EDIT:** When you wish to insert each field of your form to a specific Bootstrap div, you could use [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) solution provided by jQuery:

```
$('#insertAppointmentsForm .field-class').wrapAll('<div class="col-md-6"></div>');
```

Comment: `<div id="insertAppointmentsForm">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type=text value="sample">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type=text value="sample">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>`

Actually I need code like this. I want to add Bootstrap classes to all of input fields which was created using autoform.

Comment: Hey! I updated my problem also. I need a do something like this, not a wrap all input fields. I need to add different bootstrap classes to different input fields.

Comment: In this case you will need to check if there is some specific and unique ID's or classes on each field, and implement the `.wrapAll()` solution few times to achieve what you are looking for. I don't think there is much of an easier way, since you want it to be that specific.